# Highcharts Treemap Drilldown/drillup issue

Tags: highcharts, treemap, drilldown

I am trying to capture drill up/down event when using HighCharts treemap as in example http://jsfiddle.net/ghh1x7vt/1/

I will have to dynamically set the data label size/color as i drill down/up. Can someone help me doing this?

```
$(function () {
var data = {

        "Eastern Mediterranean": {
        "Egypt": {
            "Communicable & other Group I": "74.3",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "781.7",
                "Injuries": "33.5"
        },
            "South Sudan": {
            "Injuries": "143.4",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "831.3",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "623.4"
        },
            "Sudan": {
            "Injuries": "133.6",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "551.0",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "495.0"
        },
            "Libya": {
            "Injuries": "62.8",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "550.0",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "52.6"
        },
            "Jordan": {
            "Noncommunicable diseases": "640.3",
                "Injuries": "53.5",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "52.5"
        },
            "Pakistan": {
            "Communicable & other Group I": "296.0",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "669.3",
                "Injuries": "98.7"
        },
            "Djibouti": {
            "Noncommunicable diseases": "631.1",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "626.0",
                "Injuries": "106.0"
        },
            "Syrian Arab Republic": {
            "Communicable & other Group I": "41.0",
                "Injuries": "308.0",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "572.7"
        },
            "Morocco": {
            "Noncommunicable diseases": "707.7",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "131.5",
                "Injuries": "47.0"
        },
            "Yemen": {
            "Communicable & other Group I": "515.0",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "626.9",
                "Injuries": "84.3"
        },
            "Bahrain": {
            "Injuries": "33.5",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "505.7",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "48.5"
        },
            "United Arab Emirates": {
            "Noncommunicable diseases": "546.8",
                "Injuries": "31.5",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "35.6"
        },
            "Lebanon": {
            "Noncommunicable diseases": "384.6",
                "Injuries": "40.6",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "30.5"
        },
            "Saudi Arabia": {
            "Noncommunicable diseases": "549.4",
                "Injuries": "41.1",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "71.3"
        },
            "Iran (Islamic Republic of)": {
            "Injuries": "74.9",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "56.2",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "569.3"
        },
            "Iraq": {
            "Communicable & other Group I": "87.0",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "715.5",
                "Injuries": "128.5"
        },
            "Qatar": {
            "Communicable & other Group I": "28.3",
                "Injuries": "41.0",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "407.0"
        },
            "Afghanistan": {
            "Communicable & other Group I": "362.7",
                "Injuries": "169.2",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "846.3"
        },
            "Somalia": {
            "Noncommunicable diseases": "550.7",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "927.2",
                "Injuries": "188.5"
        },
            "Kuwait": {
            "Communicable & other Group I": "82.5",
                "Injuries": "25.4",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "406.3"
        },
            "Oman": {
            "Injuries": "52.8",
                "Noncommunicable diseases": "478.2",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "84.2"
        },
            "Tunisia": {
            "Noncommunicable diseases": "509.3",
                "Communicable & other Group I": "65.0",
                "Injuries": "39.1"
        }

    }
};
var points = [],
    region_p,
    region_val,
    region_i,
    country_p,
    country_i,
    cause_p,
    cause_i,
    cause_name = [];
cause_name['Communicable & other Group I'] = 'Communicable diseases';
cause_name['Noncommunicable diseases'] = 'Non-communicable diseases';
cause_name['Injuries'] = 'Injuries';
region_i = 0;
for (var region in data) {
    region_val = 0;
    region_p = {
        id: "id_" + region_i,
        name: region,
        color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[region_i]
    };
    country_i = 0;
    for (var country in data[region]) {
        country_p = {
            id: region_p.id + "_" + country_i,
            name: country,
            parent: region_p.id
        };
        points.push(country_p);
        cause_i = 0;
        for (var cause in data[region][country]) {
            cause_p = {
                id: country_p.id + "_" + cause_i,
                name: cause_name[cause],
                parent: country_p.id,
                value: Math.round(+data[region][country][cause])
            };
            region_val += cause_p.value;
            points.push(cause_p);
            cause_i++;
        }
        country_i++;
    }
    region_p.value = Math.round(region_val / country_i);
    points.push(region_p);
    region_i++;
}
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container',
        events: {
            redraw: function () {

                var rootNode = this.series[0].rootNode;

                if (rootNode === '') {
                    alert(' NO DRILLED - LEVEL 0 ')
                } else {
                    if (rootNode.split('_').length == 2) {
                        alert(' DRILLED - LEVEL 1');
                    } else if (rootNode.split('_').length >= 2) {
                        alert(' DRILLED - LEVEL 2');
                    }
                }

            }
        }
    },
    series: [{
        type: "treemap",
        layoutAlgorithm: 'squarified',
        allowDrillToNode: true,
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: false
        },
        levelIsConstant: false,
        levels: [{
            level: 1,
            dataLabels: {
                enabled: true
            },
            borderWidth: 3
        }],
        data: points
    }],
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Click points to drill down. Source: <a href="http://apps.who.int/gho/data/node.main.12?lang=en">WHO</a>.'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Global Mortality Rate 2012, per 100 000 population'
    }
});
```

});

Comment: How about simply setting color when creating series? Just like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ghh1x7vt/2/ (green vs blue vs red) ?

Comment: appreciate quick response. I currently have 4 levels and am displaying data labels at all levels. So it is a bit confusing as all are at same size. So i  want to set the size as i drill down/up so that the font size looks consistent. If i hard code the size, it will vary as i drill up/down. Any other ideas of achieving this?

Comment: I'm sorry, but your explanation confused me. `(...) confusing as all are at same size` and later `I want to set size (...) so that the font size looks consistent`. Font size is exactly the same across the levels? Anyway, fontSize you can set the same way as colors: http://jsfiddle.net/ghh1x7vt/3/

Comment: Apologies for confusion. He is my requirement. I have 4 levels of data and am displaying labels at all levels. So even from 1st level all child level data labels are visible and make the chart a bit confusing to read and understand what is the current level label until mouse over. So i want to change font/opacity dynamically as i drilldown/up. i.e, if i set font 12 for Level1, 10 for Level2 etc, as i move the levels when drilldown/up, i want to set the font back to 12 so that the font remains same in size across all levels. Alternatively i can also set the opacity of the font as drilldown/up.

Comment: Ok, but what is wrong with the approach I send you earlier? This demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ghh1x7vt/3

Comment: The issue is, in your example, always the data labels of current level (only one level) is displayed. But in my case, i will display data labels of all levels that means i can see all 4 levels datalabels from the level 1. So having same size or opacity of the text will confuse the user as they all look similar (though child levels text appears a bit blurred). So i want to control the size/opacity as i drill down/up.

Comment: Can you show me example with all labels displayed? I think this is not supported? Only current level's label are rendered.

Comment: here is the example: http://jsfiddle.net/ghh1x7vt/5/

In this example, Level1 & Level2 labels are displayed. However unless we mouse over the chart, it is difficult to understand that Level2 data labels are actually at level2.

So i want to differentiate other levels from Level1 by changing the font/opacity dynamically (not at design time)

Comment: So, it's something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/ghh1x7vt/6/ ? I think it's unreadable, maybe it depends on your data..

Comment: Thank for help. But i want do set the font/opacity dynamically. 

On a different issue, i am trying to show a breadcrumb with the current path in a div when i drill down/up . ex: Level1.Level2.Level3....etc as i drill up/drill down. Does anyone have any idea of achieving this as drillup/down events do NOT work for treemap.

Comment: I think the best way will be to use `dataLabels.formatter` and there set inline css, like font-size and opacity. Regarding drillup event. How about this: http://jsfiddle.net/ghh1x7vt/8/ (wrapping `drillTo` and `drillUp`) and there creating breadcrumbs?